# AudioPlay Give error

Tags: android

I am using below code to play audio file.

But it gives me error.

```
01-05 11:35:05.793: W/System.err(1739): java.lang.IllegalStateException
01-05 11:35:05.793: W/System.err(1739):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
01-05 11:35:05.793: W/System.err(1739):     at com.android.halfivrs.MyAudioControl.startAudio(MyAudioControl.java:22)
01-05 11:35:05.793: W/System.err(1739):     at com.android.halfivrs.HalfIVRSActivity.onCreate(HalfIVRSActivity.java:13)
01-05 11:35:05.793: W/System.err(1739):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-05 11:35:05.793: W/System.err(1739):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
01-05 11:35:05.793: W/System.err(1739):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
01-05 11:35:05.793: W/System.err(1739):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
01-05 11:35:05.793: W/System.err(1739):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
01-05 11:35:05.793: W/System.err(1739):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-05 11:35:05.793: W/System.err(1739):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-05 11:35:05.793: W/System.err(1739):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
01-05 11:35:05.793: W/System.err(1739):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-05 11:35:05.793: W/System.err(1739):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-05 11:35:05.793: W/System.err(1739):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-05 11:35:05.793: W/System.err(1739):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-05 11:35:05.793: W/System.err(1739):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my Code.

```
public class MyAudioControl {

    private Context mContext;

    public MyAudioControl(Context con) {
        this.mContext = con;
    }

    private MediaPlayer player;

    public void startAudio() {
        try {
            player = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, R.raw.tabla);
            player.setLooping(false); // Set looping
            player.prepare();
            player.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void stopAudio() {
        try {
            player.stop();
            player.reset();
            player.release();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Does any one has idea what's wrong with above code?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
public void startAudio() {
        player = MediaPlayer.create(ScaleTestActivity.this, R.raw.test30fps);
        player.setLooping(false); // Set looping
        player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                player.start();
            }
        });         
}
```

hope useful to you...

Comment: check file you put on raw folder is it play on other player,because i am able to play .mp3 file like this way.

Comment: @Nirav, i think that there must be an error in your log if you can't play the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
            player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.robotrock);
            player.setLooping(false); // Set looping


            playerButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.play);

            playerButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                         player.start();

                    }
                });
```